# Trajectories in orthogonal systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems, recreational-mathematics

Please forgive any awkward phrasing or misuse of terminology. My education isn't entirely formal.

**Question**

Am I right in guessing these orbits trace lissajous-ish figures on hyperspheres?

**Background**

I'm looking at what I call "trajectories" of $\textbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ in what I call "orthogonal systems" $$\dot{\textbf{x}} = \textbf{Ax}$$ (dot meaning differential), so called because $\textbf{A}$ is orthogonal.

Let's say $\textbf{A}$ has <s>no real</s> only imaginary eigenvalues. Then in 2 dimensions, the orbits are a set of concentric circles. What about 4?

I **think** it's always possible to "block-diagonalize" $\textbf{A}$ into a form I call "pairwise-decoupled":

$$\textbf{D}^{-1}\textbf{A}\textbf{D} = \left( \begin{array}{cc} \begin{array}{cc} a_{11} && a_{12} \\ a_{21} && a_{22} \end{array} && 0 \\ 0 && \begin{array}{cc} a_{33} && a_{34} \\ a_{43} && a_{44} \end{array} \end{array} \right)$$

This seems to suggest the orbits can be decomposed into circular paths in independent planes, each with a different rate of revolution, and the decomposition is possible in any even dimensionality.

Right?

Comment: The orbits are only circles in 2d when the eigenvalues have zero real part. Nonreal eigenvalues isn't enough.

Comment: Right, thanks. Question corrected.